# Can we delete our own downvoted, unhelpful but accepted answers when a user is removed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-accounts, accepted-answer

I have a negatively-scored answer which was accepted by the question OP, who's account has since been deleted. I want to delete my answer now because it really has no use. I think users should have the ability to delete these kinds of mishaps (can rarely happen), and keep their reputation safely without any risk chances.

My answer was considered unhelpful and comment edit improvements were included, so I edited it, but still turned out hopeless, and I figured this meaning nothing because the user was removed in the first place, but I didn't want to just leave my answer there for users to downvote either. If a feature request for this is not needed, can the answer for this question have information on how this can be resolved after the edit?

In total shortening, can users have the ability to **delete** useless, downvoted, accepted answers?

Comment: Whether such feature will be implemented or not, you can always flag your answer for moderator review, and request it be deleted. I've done that before on a different site, and a moderator was able to delete it

Comment: Okay,  @Wondercricket, I will try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange doesn't allow users to delete answers that have been accepted by the question asker (a.k.a. original poster/OP). This is because - in the *normal* case - this is usually a bad thing to do. If the OP thinks the answer is useful to them, chances are it will be useful to other people, so it shouldn't be deleted.

There are sometimes exceptions to the rule, like the situation you describe, where it makes more sense to override this rule and delete the answer. This is where the mod team can step in. As @Wondercricket states: flag your answer for moderator review, explain the situation, and request it be deleted. Mods are able to override a bunch of restrictions like this, for exactly these sorts of rare situations.

In any case, I have deleted the answer as requested.